# NextJS 13 standard script tag doesn't work when deployed to Vercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I'm using Next.js v. 13.4.4 , app folder, tailwind, eslint, server components enabled.

Does someone know why this standard `script` inside my layout.js Head tag gets loaded correctly on localhost, but it doesn't when deployed to Vercel?

my **layout.js** code looks like:

```
export default async function RootLayout({ children }) {

  return (
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta httpEquiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script src="../../js/myscript.js" defer />
      </head>
      <body className={`${inter.variable} font-inter`}>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

I also tried with Next.js `<Script>` tag but that doesn't work on localhost either so is even worst.

The script is a local script and it's there in the DOM both locally and on Vercel deploy, but somehow on the deploy the code in the script doesn't work.

Maybe is the code itself? Here it is anyway, a simple observer, which again, works fine locally:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".myfx");
    const callback = (entries, observer) => {
        entries.forEach((entry) => {
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                entry.target.classList.add('animate')
            }
        });
    }
    const options = {
        root: null,
        rootMargin: '0px',
        threshold: 0.5
    }
    const myObserver = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options)
    elements.forEach(el => {
        myObserver.observe(el)
    });
});
```

Comment: Why exactly would you use the `IntersectionObserver` like that, instead of using a RefObject and useEffect?

Comment: so I can get multiple elements on multiple pages at once without repeating the code in each page/component and have to worry about it being server or client at the top of that

Comment: Even that could still be achieved by using a useEffect inside a client component with `document.querySelectorAll` instead of ref object.

Comment: @FabioNettis yea you're right, it solves the problem thank you. Although I still think structurally would make more sense to keep inside a component only the code relative to that component. I had my Header component which is a "use client" so it fits well here but still.. I leave it open, since I'm curious to know why the code inside the script tag doesn't work on Vercel

Comment: That is a valid point, I'd recommend you create a dedicated client component where this `useEffect` is contained in so you do not have to mix up logic of different purposes.

Comment: I am having a similar issue with the script tag given by Microsoft Clarity. When I add the tag to the <Head> in my layout or _app.js file (i have tried both while debugging) it works locally, but it will not work when I deploy through Vercel. I started getting a next-head-count missing error just for adding the script tag. And the error only comes up after deploying to Vercel.